# Want to use objectAtIndex:indexPath.row for new query in pushed view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to carry the value of object of selected row to next view to create new array from SQLite.db. I want the new tableViewController to remember the selected word from the previous tableViewController on stack. Can't seem to find out how?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a property in the new table view controller' class files and set it when you push it onto the stack.

Search for an example of drill down table view controller.

Comment: I believe you may be able to improve the edit I made. For instance you could eventually link to https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code